# How to target different .NET version for same project dll referenced in different projects

Tags: c#, .net, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

In my Application module my Winform UI project utilize 2 ClassLibrary projects(Models & Components) which is also shared by some other projects.
All these are compiled into .Net Framework 4.0 so far. I have been given task to upgrade other projects to .Net 4.8
Problem with me is my UI project use devexpress(3rd party dll) old version which is compatible with 4.0 but not higher.
Is there any way that when i compile(Build/rebuild) my UI project then My 2 ClassLibrary projects build target to 4.0 where as when other modules compile into 4.8 then My 2 ClassLibrary projects build target to 4.8
My project structure is as follows:

- Models
- Components
- ServerUI(refer above 2 and need to convert into 4.8)
- ClientUI(refer top 2 and required to compile into 4.0)

I have searched over internet that preprocessor directives can be used to target multiple .NET Framework but unable to get the logic as how to use it.
In Visual studio when I Build ServerUI(targeting 4.8) Model & Component should also target 4.8
and  when I Build ClientUI(targeting 4.o client) Model & Component should also target 4.0

Please suggest how can I achieve this?

Comment: Convert the csproj to sdk-style project and add multiple target frameworks

Comment: What is the problem with the third party dll? In general, the .net 4.8 runtime should be backward compatible and able to run any 4.x dll. Are you sure it is not possible to just update your project?

Comment: @brz -How so? any link or detail ?

Comment: @JonasH Currently using Devexpress older version which can not be upgrade as of now since upgrading it to latest version requires many changes need to be done as devexpress itself changed many methods and process .

Comment: But what is preventing you from just using the older version? Even if it does not officially support .Net 4.8 I would still expect it to work just fine. Have you tried and got actual errors when using the older devexpress version in a .net 4.8 project?

Comment: @JonasH yes tried , when  I updated my UI application to 4.8 getting compilation error with two other dlls very old and obsolete. Since this UI is installed and currently used by  1200-1500 active users per day, management has decided not to touch this application as of now. so is the issue